# SQL query using limit while considering duplicates

Tags: sql, database, limit, querying

I'm using a query to get the top 3 records from a table using limit like so:

```
select name, salary 
from employees 
order by salary desc
limit 3;
```

The problem is there could be employees with the same salary and I wouldn't want my limit to be 3 in that case

```
----------------------------
|    name    |    salary   |
----------------------------
|   Robert   |    10000    |
|     Jon    |    20000    |
| Alexander  |    30000    |
|    James   |    20000    |
|    Mike    |    40000    |
----------------------------
```

So in this example I would want to have a limit of 4 since there are two employees with a salary of 20000. Is there a way to consider the duplicates without knowing in advance how many there will be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to first determine the salary ranges you want to include.

```
select name, salary 
  from employees 
 where salary in ( select distinct salary 
                from employees
                order by salary desc
                limit 3 )
 order by salary DESC ;
```

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I needed!